# Javascript Three.Js GLTF Loading Is Very Slow Compared To Other GLTF Viewers

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

Hello I'm trying to implement a 3D Model Viewer using Three.Js however I have a problem with the loading times and I don't know where the problem might be.

As an example I'm trying to upload this model here (download link): https://opensplit.com/gltf/assets/PromoModel.glb

You can test it In this gltf Viewer here for example: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

It will basically pops up after only a few seconds.

However you can see how ridiculously long it takes on my website: https://opensplit.com/
The same model takes now more than two minutes to load.. this cannot be correct, why is it so slow?

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>   
<br>            
<div style="margin:15px; margin-bottom:0px;">
    <progress id="load_lowPoly" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        
    <div id="lowPoly_progress">Loading Raw Model</div>
</div>
<div id="progressElement" style="background: green; width:0%;"></div>
<div id="previewquali" style="margin:15px; margin-top:0px;">
    Material Quality: loading.. 
</div>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/three.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/RGBELoader.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/EquirectangularToCubeGenerator.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/PMREMGenerator.js"></script>
<script src="../gltf/libraries/PMREMCubeUVPacker.js"></script>  

<script>
    window.addEventListener( "resize", this.onWindowResize, false );    
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();   
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
    var windowHeight = 800; 
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 47, (window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight) / windowHeight, 0.01, 100000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: document.getElementById( "canvas" ), antialias: true, alpha: true } );
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var loadAsset = true;
    var percentComplete;
    var gltfSource;
    var envMap;
    var mesh;
    onWindowResize();
    init();
    animate();
    
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = (window.innerWidth/1.15) / windowHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/1.15, windowHeight );
    }

    function init() {   
        camera.position.z = 0;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.x = 2000.00;
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/1.15, windowHeight );
        renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.gammaFactor = 2.8;
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xf2f2f2, 1 );
        updateWindow();
        createCubeMap( "../gltf/hdri/machine_shop_02_1k.hdr", 1024 );
        loadDraco6141012( "../gltf/assets/PromoModel.glb" );
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();  
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        
    };  

    function createCubeMap( src, res ) {
        new THREE.RGBELoader().setDataType( THREE.UnsignedByteType ).load( src, function ( texture ) {  
            var cubeGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: res } );
            var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( cubeGenerator.renderTarget.texture );
            var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
            envMap = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget.texture;
            cubeGenerator.update( renderer );
            pmremGenerator.update( renderer );
            pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );
            pmremGenerator.dispose();
            pmremCubeUVPacker.dispose();
        } );
    }
    
    function loadDraco6141012( src ) {
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );
        loader.load( src, function( gltf ) {
            gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.material.envMap = envMap;
                    child.material.envMapIntensity = 0.8;
                    mesh = child;
                }
            } );
            scene.add( gltf.scene );
        }, function ( xhr ) {
            if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                console.log( "Loading Model - " + Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + "%" );
                document.getElementById("lowPoly_progress").innerHTML = "Loading Raw Model " + Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + "%";
                document.getElementById("load_lowPoly").value = percentComplete;
            }
        } );
    }
                
    function updateWindow() {
        onWindowResize();
    }

</script>
```

I thought this was the most simple way to do it. But as you can see for yourself on my website this takes forever to load. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler? I.e. in Chrome in the Developer Tools in the tab "Performance"?

Comment: No, I wouldn't know what to look for.. everything works fine, it's just extremely slow..

Comment: I have an idea... As far as I can tell, your application is mostly downloading the glb file, which is not exactly small. Did you compare with the other website by dragging your downloaded file there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my guess:

Your website is slow since it has to download the glb file first, which just takes a while.

You probably compared it with Dons website by downloading the glb file to your computer and dragging it into the viewer. This way the download is already finished and everything happens locally on your computer, so you don't have to wait anymore... which is faster of course.

How could you solve problems like this in the future? Open the developer tools in Chrome, go to "Performance" and start a recording. Refresh your webpage. When the model is visible, stop the recording. Now you can see a small dropdown (or something like that) called "Network" below the rendered frames in the profiler. If you open this, you will see that loading your .glb file took 1.2 minutes.

Comment: does that mean the model has to be downloaded by the browser in order to display the model? I thought it would use the model on the server.. but how does for example sketchfab.com manage to achieve such high loading speed?

Comment: Sketchfab sends down a low-res version of the model for you to look at, while it works on downloading the high-res one.  Yes, the model needs to be locally in the client browser before it can be sent to WebGL for rendering.

Comment: @Miger For clarification: yes, the browser downloads the file and renders it. Generally speaking is a website just a program that you download and execute via your browser. That means all assets (images, video, music files, etc.) as well as the HTML, CSS and javascript part are downloaded. This is also one reason why minification is used.

Comment: ok, but how can I increase the download speed of my .glb file.. this is just way too slow and not comparable to the speed that sketchfab.com has for example

Comment: and by the way when downloading the .glb file directly by going to `https://opensplit.com/gltf/assets/PromoModel.glb` the download of the actual file is much faster than when trying to view it in ThreeJS

Comment: @Miger There aren't really good solutions to increase the actual download speed. The connection of the server can be improved, but then the machine of the end user might be the bottleneck. You could however create a lower-quality preview version of the file that would be displayed until the full version is downloaded or you could split the glb file  into multiple parts (could be multiple geometries or just geometry and other information in separate files) and load/show them one after another.

Comment: Models actually load in very fast, its the textures that take a long time. I've already experimented with the lower-quality preview until the higher-quality loads. However this still  takes way to long and cannot be compared to the implementation seen on sketchfab.. I've created a new question addressing this. If you want to help you can move over there. I think the question of this thread has been answered so far. I know now at least, that it's the download of the file that takes too long. Now I need a good solution..

Comment: @Miger Another common approach for this type of problem would be streaming. This however might be non-trivial to implement and I am not sure if it is supported (yet). If you want to read more about it, you can have a look at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/1238, it might give you some hints where to go. Personally I think this might be a bit too complicated for a first iteration and maybe loading the model without the textures first and then adding them later would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code for Dons viewer here: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer